# Most Populated WordSearch

Tags: code-challenge, word-search

Write a program to generate a rectangular word-search of size 6x9. Words may go downwards, rightwards and diagonally (downwards and to the right), they may also overlap on the board.

The challenge is to include as many different English words as possible from https://www.ef.co.uk/english-resources/english-vocabulary/top-3000-words Your program may select desirable words itself to include. You score 1 point per word included.

---

For example:

For clarity I've used "." symbols below instead of random letters.

```
dolphin..
o.....o..
g.....u..
.....ono.
.........
.........
```

The above word-search contains {'do', 'dog', 'dolphin', 'hi', 'i', 'in', 'no', 'noun', 'on', and 'phi'} so from what is filled in so far scores 10 points.

In the unlikely event of a tie the shortest code size will be used to choose a winner.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86189/discussion-on-question-by-alan2here-most-populated-wordsearch).

Comment: Right, I hope those edits have covered everyones issues. Sorry if I missed anyone out. I'll put in a reopen request.

Comment: The ptoblem with this challenge is that answers will just consist of printing the optimal wordsearch itself, rather than a program finding the wordsearch. What I'd recommend instead is having the submission take input as a list of words and returning a wordsearch within reasonable time complexity. You could turn it into a [tag:test-battery] question, where you have a series of test cases and see which submission produces the most compact wordsearchs.

Comment: @King Test batteries in this case being several specific subsets of words from the original word list?

Comment: Voting to reopen on the condition that you make it just one word search-- two is unnecessary.

Comment: @lirtosiast Wouldn't a test batteries mean that there were in effect several word-searches? Also it's only 2 because it was suggested on the Meta post about this question. I'm inclined to agree but cannot do all thease contradictory things. Do you think that a totally optimal solution will be found and reposted by all, or looking up the answer etc… and not posting code is going to be an issue? Most compact to contain all the words will be impractically large.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 20 bytes, score  <s>53</s>  57

```
“¦/œḌ⁼ƥ~ẹµḲ5&Ċd@ṡ»ḲY
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATEAzv9qZWxsef//4oCcwqHigbzJvG0h4biLVsK/wr/igb3GkSThuZkpOeG5qsK74biyWf//)**

Wordsearch:

```
a d m i s s i o n
h o u s e h o l d
s o m e t h i n g
g e n e r a l l y
p o t e n t i a l
t h e r e f o r e
```

Words:

```
admission generally household potential something therefore
general mission
house stair there thing
ally gene here hill hold miss some tent thin
air all due era for hat her ill oil old one pot see set son ten the use
ad ah at do go he hi ie in me ms oh on or so to us
i
```

---

**Previous**
...the dictionary referenced in the question has changed since this was posted so this would drop to a score of 33.

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 23 bytes, score  <s>150 154 158</s>  160

```
“RʂȥḄ0ḣq⁾÷yḊzIḥẊḥYx »ḲY
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATYAyf9qZWxsef//4oCcUsqCyKXhuIQw4bijceKBvsO3eeG4inpJ4bil4bqK4bilWXggwrvhuLJZ//8)**

Used Python to search for boards; there are, no doubt, higher scores possible though.

The board:

```
donations
beverages
placement
performed
metallica
thousands
```

The words:

```
['a', 'ac', 'ace', 'ae', 'ag', 'age', 'ages', 'al', 'all', 'am', 'an', 'and', 'ar', 'art', 'as', 'at', 'ati', 'au', 'b', 'be', 'beverage', 'beverages', 'bp', 'c', 'ca', 'cd', 'ce', 'cement', 'cf', 'd', 'da', 'das', 'db', 'do', 'don', 'donation', 'donations', 'ds', 'e', 'ec', 'ed', 'ee', 'eh', 'el', 'em', 'en', 'ent', 'er', 'era', 'es', 'et', 'ev', 'eve', 'ever', 'f', 'fa', 'fo', 'for', 'form', 'formed', 'g', 'ge', 'gem', 'h', 'ho', 'i', 'ia', 'ic', 'in', 'io', 'ion', 'l', 'la', 'lace', 'le', 'lee', 'li', 'll', 'ls', 'm', 'me', 'med', 'men', 'ment', 'met', 'meta', 'metal', 'metallic', 'metallica', 'mi', 'min', 'mr', 'mt', 'n', 'na','nat', 'nation', 'nations', 'nd', 'ne', 'nec', 'ns', 'nt', 'nv', 'o', 'oe', 'og', 'ol', 'on', 'ons', 'or', 'ou', 'p', 'pe', 'per', 'perform', 'performed', 'pl', 'place', 'placement', 'pm', 'pp', 'ppm', 'r', 'ra', 'rage', 're', 'rf', 'rl', 'rm', 'rt', 's', 'sa', 'san', 'sand', 'ss', 'st', 'std', 't', 'ta', 'tall', 'td', 'th', 'thou', 'thousand', 'thousands', 'ti', 'tion', 'tions', 'to', 'tr', 'treo', 'u', 'us', 'usa', 'v', 'va', 'var', 've', 'ver']
```

---

#### The search

Note `LIMIT_TO_N_BEST_NINES` limits the search - lower numbers try fewer boards by never using the lower scoring rows (nine letter words) which will find "good" scores quicker, while higher numbers (up to 909 - the number of 9 letter words in the dictionary) will search more boards (and likely never complete!).

```python
f = open(filePath, 'r')
ws = set(w.replace('\n', '').lower() for w in f.readlines())

def iterSubWords(w, ws):
    for l in range(1,len(w)+1):
        for s in range(len(w)-l+1):
            if w[s:s+l] in ws: yield w[s:s+l]

nines = sorted([w for w in ws if len(w) == 9], key=lambda w:len(tuple(iterSubWords(w, ws))), reverse=1)

def diags(rows):
    for rs in range(len(rows)):
        yield ''.join(rows[rs + x][x] for x in range(min(len(rows) - rs, len(rows[0]))))
    for cs in range(1, len(rows[0])):
        yield ''.join(rows[x][cs + x] for x in range(min(len(rows[0]) - cs, len(rows))))

def diagWords(rows, validWords):
    for d in diags(rows):
        for sw in iterSubWords(d, validWords): yield sw

def allWordsOnBoard(rows, validWords):
    r = set()
    for row in list(rows) + [''.join(col) for col in zip(*rows)]:
        for validWord in iterSubWords(row, validWords): r.add(validWord)
    for validWord in diagWords(rows, validWords): r.add(validWord)
    return r

from itertools import combinations, permutations

LIMIT_TO_N_BEST_NINES = 107

m = 0
for wl in combinations(nines[:LIMIT_TO_N_BEST_NINES], 6):
    fws = allWordsOnBoard(wl, ws)
    if len(fws) > m:
        for p in permutations(wl):
            fws = allWordsOnBoard(p, ws)
            if len(fws) > m:
                m = len(fws)
                print(m, p)
```

Comment: Are all of your examples words? Some of them look like just plain letters of the alphabet ('m', 'n', 'l', etc...). Also, I don't think many of the two letter examples are words either ('aa', 'ht', 'nn', etc...).

Comment: I'm using the linked dictionary.

Comment: This challenge is off to a worrisome start. You're using 'words' from a list that contains many that aren't words in the English language. I'm strictly using English, but none of my words show up in that list! And these are the only two answers so far.

Comment: I am following the specification :(

Comment: Maybe the specification should be edited to remove the specific reference to English? That might make it better....

Comment: @ouflak, challenge specs trump everything here. Even reality!

Comment: @Shaggy, I'm fine with that. But the spec does say English.

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 73 bytes - <strike>49</strike> <strike>66</strike> <strike>74</strike> 75 words

```lua
print("abraiders\nscrapings\nsheathers\ncarabiner\nbrahmanis\nrelapsers")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HctBDoAgDAXRu7DSO7H5YiNNoDQtnr8iu8lLpr2IUGOZR8Jl4JvMsxg1qO/0YlCW589KmHVrGV1pLs6yrtoh7OmM@AA)

I got the words from another StackExchange question on the [Puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/9890/the-most-words-that-can-be-made-by-successively-adding-one-letter-to-the-origina) site. Prints:

```lua
abraiders
scrapings
sheathers
carabiner
brahmanis
relapsers
```

So it's a minimum of eight words each row for 48 words, plus the indefinite article 'a' for 49 words horizontally. **Edit**: It seems there was an edit to the challenge and there now may be a limit to a list of very specific words and, unlike all of the words forming my list, not all of those words are actually even English. *sigh* Might just leave this here for posterity.

**Edit**
Words formed horizontally:

```lua
i (pronoun 'I')
id
aid
aide
raid
aider
braid
aiders
raider
raiders
braiders
abraiders

la
lap
laps
lapse
elapse
relapse
relapser
relapsers

in
pin
rap
ping
crap
pings
aping
scrap
raping
craping
scraping
scrapings

at
he
eat 
her 
she 
the 
eath
heat
hers
heath
sheath
sheathe
sheather
sheathers

a
ab
rab
bin
car
arab
arabi
arabin
arabine
carabine
carabiner

is
ra
rah
man
bra
rahm
brahm
brahma
brahman
brahmani
brahmanis
```

Words formed vertically:

```lua
as
aha
are
ass
era
char
hare
```

Comment: Use the dictionary in the question, all single letters are words for example.

Comment: Formed my answer before that edit. Darn!

Comment: Are there any words vertically in this?

Comment: Yes, I've done some reshuffling and am slowly editing the word count to include those. I was going for a maximum along the 9 length row to have the most possible words right from the start.

Comment: I think I might need to edit my answer to show all of the possible words.

Comment: I *count* 95 words (from the list): `['a','aa','aaa','ab','ah','ai','aid','an','ap','api','ar','arab','as','ass','at','b','bc','bi','bin','bm','br','bra','c','ca','car','cb','ch','char','cr','crap','d','de','der','di','e','ea','eat','el','en','er','era','g','gr','h','ha','he','heat','heath','heather','her','hi','i','ia','id','ide','in','ing','ip','l','la','lap','m','ma','man','n','ne','ng','ni','nn','p','pi','pin','ping','ps','pt','r','ra','raid','rap','re','rg','rr','rs','s','sc','se','ser','sh','she','sr','ss','t','tb','th','the']`

Comment: Sorry @ouflak, I'm not doing this to mess you around. I'm trying to address peoples issues with the question, I've made a meta post about this too.

Comment: @ouflak There good words listed in your answer. Thank you. It's the closest so far to the answer I'd like to mark as correct.